# an issue on "if statement" in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

Take a look on the following java code.

```
String Remark="";
boolean Paid, PartiallyPaid, NotPaid;
if(Paid=true) {Remark="Paid";}
if(PartiallyPaid=true) {Remark="Partially Paid";}
if(NotPaid=true)  {Remark="Not Paid";}
```

Here the Boolean values determined by RadioButtons. I want to assign the string "Remark" as mentioned above. But It always giving the last assigning value only(as "Not Paid"). Anyone explain why this is occurring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `==` instead of `=` for comparison.

`==` is used to compare two values for equality

`=` is used for assigning one value to another

```
String Remark="";
boolean Paid, PartiallyPaid, NotPaid;  // initialise values else compile error, pointed out by  Peter O.
if(Paid==true) {Remark="Paid";}
if(PartiallyPaid==true) {Remark="Partially Paid";}
if(NotPaid==true)  {Remark="Not Paid";}
```

As pointed out by unholysampler

for boolean values you dont have to explicitly check for equality. Following would do

```
String Remark="";
boolean Paid, PartiallyPaid, NotPaid;  // initialise values else compile error, pointed out by  Peter O.
if(Paid) {Remark="Paid";}
if(PartiallyPaid) {Remark="Partially Paid";}
if(NotPaid)  {Remark="Not Paid";}
```

Comment: Also, if the variable is a boolean, you don't need to explicitly compare it to `true`.

Comment: @unholysampler Thank you. I have updated answer based on your input

Comment: Note that the second block of code won't even compile anymore, since the three boolean variables are now uninitialized.

Comment: @PeterO. Thank you. Missed that. Updated answer by adding comment

Answer (score 0):

Here, `if(Paid=true)` should be `if(Paid==true)`. Same thing  with all other similar cases. `=` is assignment. You're giving Paid a value of `true`. `==` is a test for equivalence of primitive types. It should look like this:

```
String Remark="";
boolean Paid, PartiallyPaid, NotPaid;
if(Paid) {
     Remark="Paid";
} else if(PartiallyPaid) {
     Remark="Partially Paid";
} else if(NotPaid)  {
     Remark="Not Paid";
}
```

However, your booleans are all currently false. And it seems that simultaneously it can be be all 3 options, which is not a good idea. You should look up if/else statements in Java documentation.

Comment: O.K. but the assigning a value in to the String "Remark" is became null. What I suppose to do to assigning correctly?

Comment: You assigned it to null in your first line. You're not allowed to assign within `if` statements. I'll post what your code should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double equals in the if statement.

Comment: O.K. but the assigning a value in to the String "Remark" is became null. What I suppose to do to assigning correctly?

Comment: For string comparison you have to use .equals. For comparing strings to not null, you should just use if (string).